# My URL returns Json in Browser But not works in Postman

Tags: php, json, server, localhost, postman

I have a test [URL](http://onesignaldemo.rf.gd/test/get_user.php) which returns a Json Result as following

```
{"result":[{"Users":{"id":"1","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"2","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"3","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"4","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"5","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"6","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"7","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"8","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"9","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"10","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"11","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"12","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}}],"error_code":1}
```

My Problem is When i run this [URL](http://onesignaldemo.rf.gd/test/get_user.php) On **Chrome Browser** It returns the Correct response as mentioned above.But incase of **Postman** it returns errors with the following message

**This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support**

PS: In localhost it  [http://localhost/test/get_user.php] works fine in both **Browser and PostMan.**

Comment: It means that the url you are trying to hit explicitly prohibits scraping.

Comment: @dimi How should i Avoid this..??

Comment: First of all, this means that you should not be doing that. But if you are completely sure that scraping that website does not violate usage policy, then you can use headless browser that parses javascript (example http://phantomjs.org/ )

Comment: @Dimi Thanks for Your Answers. The Problem With Server Response

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally, I found that the problem is from Server Side.I have used the free hosting called [Infinity Free](http://infinityfree.net) in that they won't allow scraping. Now I am migrated to [000WebHost](https://www.000webhost.com/)