# Error in Downloading data from mysql to Android

Tags: javascript, php, android, mysql

getting error related to javascript in downloading data from mysql to android
...when i show the string downloaded it shows a html page which i included in image...kindly help me to get out of it soon.

Downloaded String "sb" is made as Toast here and it shows like this:

[image: Downloaded String "sb" is made as Toast here and it shows like this]

Code:

```
public class Download extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,String>{
Context c;
String address;
ProgressDialog pd;
public Download(Context c,String address){
    this.c=c;
    this.address=address;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    pd.dismiss();
    if(s!=null){
        Toast.makeText(c,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(c,"download failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Download");
    pd.setMessage("Fetching Data...");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String data=downloaddata();
    return data;
}
public String downloaddata() {
    InputStream is=null;
    String line=null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        is=con.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
    if(br!=null){
        while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
        sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
        br.close();is.close();con.disconnect();
    }
        else{
        return null;
    }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(is!=null){
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: When i checked in browser it shows correctly...error is only on the app

Comment: tried out now...html page shows the same as the toast on get,post,....

Comment: Got my solution by transferring my host site to other...its error with the hosting site...thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not error Something related to [**Web scraping**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)
For more info Check this [**thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43132038/5740760)

Answer (score 0):

You should define for what purpose you are opening connection.

```
HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

And also you are not connected with your connection.
You must write 
`con.connect();` 
for connecting.
Once connected with your network then you can use your code  to get the stream data 
`InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();`

May these will help you.