# login using volley libary works on emulator or localhost but not in online server

Tags: php, android

I just one to login into another activity , the codes work fine when emulator. To make it online login the codes always return failure message. While the username and password are correct.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Defining views
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private Button buttonLogin;
private boolean loggedIn = false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

    buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

         buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"hello log me",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            login();
        }

    });

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //In onresume fetching value from sharedpreference
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Fetching the boolean value form sharedpreferences
    loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

    //If we will get true
    if(loggedIn){
        //We will start the Profile Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}


private void login(){
    //Getting values from edit texts
    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,email,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,password,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                   // If we are getting success from server
                    if(response.trim().equals("success")){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                       startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("Else Error",response.toString());
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //You can handle error here if you want
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hi there is "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("Hello",error.toString());
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            //Adding parameters to request
            params.put(Config.KEY_EMAIL, email);
            Log.d("Email :",email);
            params.put(Config.KEY_PASSWORD, password);
            Log.d("PASSWORD :",password);

            //returning parameter
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Adding the string request to the queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
}
```

Config.java

```
public class Config {
//URL to our login.php file

//public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/android/login.php";
public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://test.codeachi.com/Andi/android/login.php";

//Keys for email and password as defined in our $_POST['key'] in login.php
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "username";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

//If server response is equal to this that means login is successful
public static final String LOGIN_SUCCESS = "success";

//Keys for Sharedpreferences
//This would be the name of our shared preferences
public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "myloginapp";

//This would be used to store the email of current logged in user
public static final String EMAIL_SHARED_PREF = "email";

//We will use this to store the boolean in sharedpreference to track user is loggedin or not
public static final String LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF = "loggedin";

}
```

login.php

```
  <?php

  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  $username = "naaz"; //$_POST['username'];
  $password = "1234"; //$_POST['password'];
  require_once('dbConnect.php');
  $sql ="SELECT * FROM volley WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  $check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  if(isset($check)){
  echo 'success';
  }else{
  echo 'failure';
  }
  }
  ?>
```

the code works fine when LOGIN_URL ="http://10.0.2.2/android/login.php"; but when the LOGIN_URL = "http://test.codeachi.com/Andi/android/login.php";
its always return failure message.

Comment: check web service .show error message

Comment: Sir what will i check on web server ??

Comment: Debug please . Use `POSTMAN` . I am not SIR

Comment: 08-30 12:34:32.890 2779-2779/com.example.user.volleyuse D/Else Error: failure

Comment: when hit on button

Comment: I have also faced the same Issues Because of the My Free Hosting Site won't respond Properly, Even in POSTMAN also it doesn't Work.  Finally, I migrated to [000WebHost][1]  Now it works Fine..!! 
Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43132038/5740760

Answer (score 1):

try other webhosting service , i suggest https://www.000webhost.com/